# How computer shows us the result of 0.7 when we add 0.1 and 0.6 in calculator?

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy, floating-point-conversion, single-precision

---

1) As I know, the computer converts the **decimal numbers** to **binary digits** and transacts as it. For example, when we add the **decimal numbers** like "12" and "37" in computer's calculator. Is it correct?

---

2) If first of my question is correct, how the **binary expression** at below is interpreted by CPU in single precision? (How the result is shown us? How the computer convert this expression which was converted to **floating point numbers** to **decimal** again? and How can we convert this expression which was converted to **floating point numbers** to **decimal** again?)

**0 ll 01111110 ll 01100110011001100110100**

I mean how we knew the result is 0.70000005 in single precision in this expression: [Floating Point Arithmetic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KiWz-mGFqHI)

---

3) As I know, the computer does same transactions as in the video I shared when we add **decimally** 0.1 and 0.6 in computer's calculator. However, the calculator hides .0000005 **binary section** from us (as in the video result) and shows us **decimal number** “0.7” as a result but how it hide or delete that section? Why it didn't showed us a number like 0.71 by rounding the,

0 ll 01111110 ll 01100110011001100110100 **floating point number**?

---

Comment: This looks a look like homework to me, please try to ask more specific questions, SO is not a site for other people to finish your homework.

Comment: @Jan Henke My homework was just converting the decimal numbers to floating point numbers and I've done it. The things I write at up are my curiosity.